# Cannot assign value of type int to value of type int Swift 2

Tags: swift

```
var endLevelY = 0 - class variable

    let levelPlist = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Level01", ofType: "plist")
    let levelData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: levelPlist!)
endLevelY = levelData["EndY"]!.integerValue! -- inside viewDidLoad()
```

It keeps saying Cannot assign value of type int to value of type int.

Thanks!

Comment: It says int with lower case as you describe?

Comment: sorry i meant capital as in Int. "Cannot assign value of type Int to value of type Int"

Comment: Please [edit] to add more of the code here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would probably help you get better answers. Thanks!